# Fancybox loading small white square

Tags: custom-post-types

I know there is a similar topic with same title, but my problem is not the same.Fancybox was working perfectly in my html template, but after converting it to wordpress, images are not showing in the popup box, I can only see a square white box

here is my code:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="portfolio-item"> 
    <a class="project-img-container">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="project-title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" class="project-img fancybox"></a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="project-link"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

& here is the js:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({

        padding     : 0,
        margin      : 100,
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        openSpeed   : 400,
        closeSpeed  : 400,

        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                css : {
                    'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm not a pro. so couldn't find the mistake myself. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inserted wrong thumb functions for large fancybox image URLs.

```
<a href="<?php get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" class="project-img fancybox"></a>
```

This get_the_post_thumbnail() returns an HTML image element but you need URL of image.
Your first code should be like this.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$thumb_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' ); ?>
<div class="portfolio-item"> 
    <a class="project-img-container">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="project-title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $thumb_image_url[0]; ?>" class="project-img fancybox"></a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="project-link"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: thank you very much, you are awesome. spent a lot of hours on this today. changed my code at least 50 times upon different suggestion & at last you provided the right solution.

by the way what does [0] means after $thumb_image_url?
I'm still in the learning stage at php, so if you could tell me or give me a link, so I can study about it, that would be great!

Comment: Actually I am returning attachment array items in $thumb_image_url variables. And this array contains 4 items. [0] => url, [1] => image width, [2] => image height, [3] => boolean: for resized image or the original. So $thumb_image_url[0] outputs image URL. :)

Comment: great. learned a lot of things. I'm in love with this community! :)